# How to pass the body of a request as a stream to a websocket without corrupting data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to get the request body as a stream and while it's uploading, pass it to a web socket. This is my current implementation:

```
        InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
        int total = 0;
        int bytes;
        byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
        while ((bytes = is.read(buff)) != -1) {
            total = total + bytes;
            this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("test", Arrays.toString(buff));
        }
        this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("test", "END");
```

When sending it now, I'm not sure if the data gets corrupted or duplciated but I can't parse the request. Once the data is sent over, I send `END` so I know that I can parse the data on the frontend.

Comment: If you add a log before the `convertAndSend` with the content of `buff` is it correct? Is your payload correctly serialized? Do you get any exception?

Comment: It seems that the problem is that I sometimes receive the `END` message before receiving the entire body stream. I can also see that the for some reason, it seems that the buffer doesn't reset, i.e. in the first request it's 4000 (should be 8000), and in a second separate request it's 12 000.

Comment: is.read will read available bytes up to at most the buffer size. If your buffer really contains 12000 bytes (which I doubt) there's a serious bug in the JVM. It's hard to say why you get and EOF earlier than you expected without information on your data source...